# How do I create a consent screen in Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I've been using Google App Engine for Python for a while now with webapp2. Until now I've been doing the following to get access to user accounts:

```
    user = users.get_current_user()
```

However, I'm pretty sure that this isn't really an "app". Normal GAE apps have a concept screen to "approve" and have to exchange API keys etc, under the hood. How do I do this with Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "normal GAE apps", I mean it really depends on what your app is doing. If you want to act on behalf of the user then yes you need to use an OAuth2 authentication flow, so the user can allow your app accessing his data.

A good starting point for you would be [this example app](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/python#authorization) which explains how to create this flow in Python to access the user's Google Drive.