# Google Accounts API: Consent screen/account chooser displayed for some - why?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-authentication

We have an application deployed in Google App Engine and are using the default Google Accounts API authentication, e.g. everyone is redirected via the standard UserServiceFactory.getUserService().createLoginURL(callback) to something like "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=...." and prompted to login to their Google account if not already.

My question: why does *some* users get to see a "consent screen" like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHplK.png

while others (majority) do not? To clarify, there is no other interaction with their accounts (no oath2 stuff for calendar or drive api etc) and they do not have more than one available accounts to select from.

Thanks!

**Edit 2016-01-07**

It is not connected to cookies and/or cached browser data - we tried multiple scenarios for users who never see the consent screen, always starting with a fully cleared browser:

1) if the website is opened straight away, user is prompted to enter his google account data (email and password), then its redirected back to the website - no consent screen (nothing about our application requesting anything)

2) if the user goes first to gmail.com, logs in and then visits the website, the redirect and login is immediate, no consent screen or account chooser

If I reverse the question: how can one force the consent screen to display at all :-)

Comment: The key difference should be whether the user's browser has cookies showing they're logged in to their google account. To verify, clear all cookies: right afterwards, the consent screen *should* be shown.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip - I updated the question

Comment: Hm, It *IS* connected to cookies, quite opposite to what you say, based on your own observation "starting with a fully cleared browser" -- if the user logs in to gmail.com that makes the cookies allowing the bypass of the consent screen. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978631/how-do-i-create-a-consent-screen-in-google-app-engine-python , you need an oauth2 flow, e.g for Java https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2 , w/some scope the user will have to approve.

Comment: I believe "full-blown" Oauth2 flow with scopes is needed when you actually want to do actions on behalf of the users and/or access his information (besides the basic email), but it is not needed for simple identity login - otherwise why would there be the UserServiceFactory.getUserService() ekosystem in the first place? Anyways, my issue is that only SOME users see the consent/account choosing screen (very dated also - see the screenshot, its nothing like the "modern" account chooser), while MOST of us never seen it (and I for one cant even simulate it using my own account).

Comment: You DID say "if the website is opened straight away, user is prompted to enter his google account data" confirming my first diagnosis -- i.e try from a fresh incognito window or after clearing all cookies/local storage. Most of us are usually logged in to some Google services, haven't just wiped out all cookies and local storage, aren't working in a brand-new incognito window -- to force consent screen despite this, explicit asking for an oauth2 scope is the only way I can think. The "ekosystem" (sic) you mention exists because most apps don't WANT to force consent screens as you do!

Comment: Sorry, I think I mislead the discussion with that "reverse question" - my original goal is to get rid of the unwanted "consent screen" (or account chooser or whatever that dated thing is). Anyways, I still dont believe the problem we are facing is tied to cookies/login status to Google services, as the "modern account chooser", "modern login screen" and "somewhat dated legacy consent screen" are 3 separate screens, and only the very last one is displayed to some users, being previously logged or not, but not to all, for no apparent reason. Appreciating your time nevertheless.